# How to store this JSON string into an API view model?

Tags: asp.net, json, database, api, viewmodel

I have this JSON string.

```
{
            "line_items": {
                            "item1": {
                                            "name": "Album #1",
                                            "sku": "WA01",
                                            "fee_taxes": {
                                                            "total": {
                                                                            "1": "1.62"
                                                            },
                                                            "subtotal": {
                                                                            "1": "1.8"
                                                            }
                                            }
                            },
                            "item2": {
                                            "name": "Single #1",
                                            "sku": "WS01",
                                            "fee_taxes": {
                                                            "total": {
                                                                            "1": "0.54"
                                                            },
                                                            "subtotal": {
                                                                            "1": "0.6"
                                                            }
                                            }
                            }
            }
```

}

We are using APIs and C# ASP.NET. 
**I need** to store the JSON into a list / array inside a view model. 
I this is not feasible. I would personally change the JSON brackets to [] to make it an array of items. I have been told not to do this because this is what the client gave us. Is it possible and how? Thank you.

Comment: What does that even mean? It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Are you asking how to parse this to a strongly typed object? Or how to store a string in a class?

Answer (score -1):

What you have here is `"line_items"` that has the keys of `"item1"` and `"item2"`. Because of this, you would have to either manually parse the JSON object out to store the keys and values in a separate object or push back for a properly formatted JSON file with the brackets as you described.

Comment: No. `item1` and `item2` are keys for a `Dictionary<string, LineItem>`. There is no need to manually parse or ask for different JSON.

Comment: Sorry to say that it has not worked. I have even try passing it as a string but throws the same error at line_items.item1. I can't manually parse it.